# Publish Multiple Pictures in one shot from master page library

Tags: 2013, document-library, picture-library, picture

When I created a master page from html using share point design manager the pictures in images folder are not published. I have to go to the images folder and select one by one to publish it. Is there any way I checked the images I would like to publish and can publish all 300+ pictures in one click instead of one by one? Cause when I checked more than one picture the publish option on top became disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before uploading pictures you can turn off versioning for the Master Page Gallery, which will ensure all files will be in approved state. You can do this by:

1. On the *Master Page Gallery*, click *Library Settings*.
2. On Settings page, click *Versioning settings*.
3. On the *Versioning Settings* , in the *Content Approval* section,
   for *Require content approval* for submitted items, select **No**.
4. In the *Document Version History* section, for *Create a version each
   time you edit a file in this document library*, select **No versioning**.
5. In the *Require Check Out* section, for *Require documents to be
   checked out before they can be edited*, select **No**.

Answer (score 0):

**After** uploading pictures, you can follow the @Falak Mahmood method and do whatever change on any column. This action will increase the version from a minor to a major version.